# Caching Policy for React or Redux Toolkit Query - based on route session

Tags: redux-toolkit, react-query

I am trying to study various caching policies and mechanisms possible for react query and RTK Query for my async data.

1 common use case is to fetch once on per route.

Let's say there are 2 routes - /X and /Y configured on react router.

when User comes to /X

data is fetched and cached once - and any component inside /X can use it. If multiple components call it - they get the same data.

Then if route changes to /Y and then back again to /X - then data is again refetched.

Is there any unique key produced when the route loads which can be used to set the cache key for this ?